# What is the size of metadata in a postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, memory

There is a table in postgres 9.4 with following types of columns:

```
 NAME                         TYPE                       TYPE SIZE
 id                         | integer                  | 4 bytes
 timestamp                  | timestamp with time zone | 8 bytes 
 num_seconds                | double precision         | 8 bytes
 count                      | integer                  | 4 bytes
 total                      | double precision         | 8 bytes
 min                        | double precision         | 8 bytes
 max                        | double precision         | 8 bytes
 local_counter              | integer                  | 4 bytes
 global_counter             | integer                  | 4 bytes                                                                     
 discrete_value             | integer                  | 4 bytes
```

Giving in total: `60 bytes per row`

The size of a table(with toast) returned by `pg_table_size(table)` is: `49 152 bytes`
Number of rows in the table: `97`

Taking into account that a table is split into pages of `8kB`, we can fit `49 152/8 192 = 6 pages` into this table.

Each page and each row has some [meta-data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/storage-page-layout.html)...
Looking at the pure datatype size we should expect something around `97 * 60 = 5 820 bytes` of row data and adding approximately the same amount of metadata to it, we are not landing even close to the result returned by `pg_table_size`: 49 152 bytes.

Does metadata really take ~9x space compared to the pure data in postgres?

Comment: What do you get after you run `vacuum full the_table;`?

Comment: now it is ```16 384 bytes```.  Taking into account that nothing has ever been deleted from the table it's a huge result for vacuuming, moreover I cannot ```vacuum full``` the database when it's in use due to locking.

Comment: What is the point of counting kilobytes on disc? Generate a million rows and see the usage then. If you are working in an extremely limited environment, maybe Pg is not the right choice...

Comment: Bloat is not only caused by DELETE but also by UPDATEs - especially if you have long running transactions and autovacuum can't deal with the old rows

Comment: "Taking into account that nothing has ever been deleted from the table it's a huge result for vacuuming, moreover I cannot vacuum full the database when it's in use due to locking"  I thought your goal was to understand.  Are you actually worried about 32kB as a pragmatic concern?

Answer (score 2):

A factor 9 is clearly more wasted space ("bloat") than there should be:

- Each page has a 16-byte header.
- Each row has a 23-byte "tuple header".
- There will be four bytes of padding between `id` and `timestamp` and between `count` and `total` for alignment reasons (you can avoid that by reordering the columns).
- Moreover, each tuple has a "line pointer" of two bytes in the data page.

See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246246/176905) for some details.

To see exactly how the space in your table is used, install the `pgstattuple` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
```

and use the `pgstattuple` function on the table:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('tablename');
```

Comment: As mentioned above, after vacuuming the size dropped from 49kB to 16kB. I don't know what ```vacuum full``` did, but the only thing I suspect that might explode the bloat is that we insert several entries in the beginning of an hour and within this hour we update it every minute and these update left the junk .

Comment: Right, mass `UPDATE`s will cause bloat.